# How to use tslint with npx

Tags: typescript, npm, tslint, npx

I have a project that has `tslint` and `typescript` locally installed.
I want to run `tslint` against the files so I am doing this:

`npx tslint -c tsconfig.json 'src/**/*.ts?(x)'`

But the command has no effect. That is what I am only see in console:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe"  "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npx\index.js" tslint -c tsconfig.json 'src/**/*.ts?(x)'
```

Any thoughts?

> tslint: 5.7.0
>   node: 8.9.1
>   npm: 5.5.1
>   npx: 9.7.1
>   os: windows10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
npx tslint -c tslint.json "src/**/*.ts?(x)"
```

(of course file naming is up to you, but probably you meant to pass tslint.json, tsconfig.json is usually typescript configuration)